# Is it possible to set default values for a DTO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

Is there some way to use default values when a query is empty?

If I have the following DTO for a query:

```
export class MyQuery {
  readonly myQueryItem: string;
}
```

And my request contains no query, then `myQuery.myQueryItem` will be undefined. How do I make it so it has a default value ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can set default directly in your DTO class:

```
export class MyQuery {
  readonly myQueryItem = 'mydefault';
}
```

You have to instantiate the class so that the default value is used. For that you can for example use the `ValidationPipe` with the option `transform: true`. If the value is set by your query params it will be overriden.

```
@Get()
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
getHello(@Query() query: MyQuery) {
  return query;
}
```

### Why does this work?

1) Pipes are applied to all your decorators, e.g. `@Body()`, `@Param()`, `@Query()` and can transform the values (e.g. `ParseIntPipe`) or perform checks (e.g. `ValidationPipe`).

2) The `ValidationPipe` internally uses `class-validator` and `class-transformer` for validation. To be able to perform validation on your input (plain javascript objects) it first has to transform them to your annotated dto class meaning it creates an instance of your class. With the setting `transform: true` it will automatically create an instance of your dto class.

Example (basically how it works):

```
class Person {
  firstname: string;
  lastname?: string = 'May';

  constructor(person) {
    Object.assign(this, person);
  }
}

// You can use Person as a type for a plain object -> no default value
const personInput: Person = { firstname: 'Yuna' };

// When an actual instance of the class is created, it uses the default value
const personInstance: Person = new Person(personInput);
```

Comment: I tried doing this. First, I had to `npm install class-validator`. Then I got the following message in the console when sending a request: `No metadata found. There is more than once class-validator version installed probably. You need to flatten your dependencies`. And I can't manage to understand what's going wrong (Google is of no help here).

Comment: Yes, you need to install both `class-validator` and `class-transformer`. Make sure that `class-validator` is listed only once in your `package.json`. Then try reinstalling your dependencies with `npm ci`.

Comment: I ensured my package.json contains both of these packages once each, and did `npm ci`, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Could you please explain me how the ValidationPipe works? For now I still can't get the magic of it. ValidationPipe is a kind of middleware, right? I can apply it to the function (like in our example), or to a specific DTO (`@Query(new ValidationPipe())`), right? What exactly does `tranform: true`? Why is it needed to use the default values of a DTO and why aren't these default values used otherwise?

Comment: This does not work with class-validator

Comment: This answer is incomplete. You need to also set `transformOptions: { exposeDefaultValues: true }` in the options for `ValidationPipe`.

Comment: Not sure why, but I verified this over and over with all the recommendations, and at least on NestJS common v8.4.3 and class-validator v0.13.2, I only had to set `transform` to `true` to get this to work as described.

Answer (score 0):

Here I want to set the default value of a status

```
export class CreateOrderDto {
  @IsInt()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  cost: number;
    
  @IsEnum(ORDER_STATUS)
  @IsString()
  status: string;
    
  constructor(partial: Partial<CreateOrderDto>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
    this.status = this.status || 'Pending';
  }
}
```